# Powershell enumerate properties of properties

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a commandlet that gathers information from a device register:

> PS C:\windows\system32> Get-PSDevice serverA
>
> HostName: ServerA
>   OOB:
>   Criticality: Normal
>   IsVirtual: True

etc

Some of these have an array of 'sub properties' inside, for example:

> Cluster                            : @{Url=https://ps-apps.com/DeviceRegister/api/Clusters/62; VCenterUrl=https://ps-apps.com/DeviceRegister/api/VCenters/2; ClusterId=62; VCenterId=2; Name=Vcenter 1 ABC Prod; 
>                                        DataCenterUrl=https://ps-apps.com/DeviceRegister/api/DataCenters/3; DataCenter=; IsValidated=True; IsExceptionCluster=False; SupportsProdWorkloads=False; SupportsNonProdWorkloads=False; SupportsSqlWorkloads=False; 
>                                        ManagedByabc=False}

I can get whatever property within the aray I want using something like:

`(Get-PSDevice ServerA).cluster.name`

I'm trying to determine a way to enumerate all of the sub properties using a foreach type statement to populate a value.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every object in PowerShell has a hidden `.PSObject` property which tells you things about the object. One of *its* properties is a `.Properties` property (as PetSerAl points out, it's not a property but in fact a `MemberSet`, though you access it with property semantics).

```
(Get-PSDevice ServerA).cluster.PSObject.Properties
```

That would return `[PSProperty]` objects that show you the information about the properties (the name, value, type, whether it's gettable and settable, etc.).

Comment: Just to be pedantic, `.PSObject` is not property, but member set: `(''|gm -Force PSObject).MemberType`.

Comment: @PetSerAl fair 'nough :)